# Reverse order of a list

Tags: list, sorting, sortedlist

I am trying to write a python code to switch the order of the list (from A to Z:input, the output should print from Z to A). My code is not giving me the right output. I need help please

```
 winners = ['Alice Munro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Rainer ``Weiss', 'Youyou Tu']
z_winners=sorted(winners, key=lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1])
```

my output is :

```
['Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Alice Munro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Youyou Tu', 'Rainer Weiss', 'Malala Yousafzai']
```

Instead of :

```
['Youyou Tu', 'Rainer Weiss', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Alice Munro']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
winners = ['Alice Munro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Rainer Weiss', 'Youyou Tu']

z_winners=sorted(winners, reverse=True)

print(z_winners)
```

By the way, you have extra '`' in your list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Write code to switch the order of the winners list so that it is now Z to A.  Then assign this list to the variable z_winners.

```
winners = ['Alice Munro', 'Alvin E. Roth', 'Kazuo Ishiguro', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Rainer Weiss', 'Youyou Tu']
winners.sort(reverse=True)
z_winners = winners
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to **sort the list by first name from Z to A**. But, you are actually using the last name to sort the list. **Instead of [-1] use [0]** to sort the list by first name.

```py
z_winners = sorted(winners, key=lambda full_name: full_name.split()[0], reverse=True)
print(z_winners)
```